# Pytest skip looking for indirect parameter if not passed?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-decorators

Let's say I have 2 files `conftest.py` and `testcases.py`. In `conftest.py` I have a `@pytest.fixture` function which accepts a parameter passed indirectly from a function in `testcases.py` (*see example below*).

conftest.py

```
    @pytest.fixture()
    def func_in_conftest(passed_parameter):
        if passed_parameter == something:
           do_something()
```

testcases.py

```
      @pytest.mark.parametrize('passed_parameter', ['some_scenario'])
      def test1(func_in_conftest):
          some_testing
    
      

      def test2(func_in_conftest):
          some_testing2
```

The tests fail when I don't pass `passed_parameter` in `test2`. I was wondering if there's a way to check if `passed_parameter` is existing and if it's not -> skip the if check.

Another solution that I tried was to pass this parameter with generic value in the tests where I don't need it. It worked partially but if I had tests depending on another test, they just got skipped. I don't understand why? Example (`conftest.py` remains the same):

testcases.py

```
  @pytest.mark.parametrize('passed_parameter', ['all'])
  @pytest.mark.dependency()
  def test1(func_in_conftest):
      some_testing


  @pytest.mark.dependency(depends=["test1"])
  def test2(func_in_conftest):
      some_testing2
```

If I add `@pytest.mark.parametrize(passed_parameter, [all])` to `test2` it still gets skipped. I couldn't find any solutions to these so I decided to post.
I'm using pytest 5.4.1 and pythton 3.7.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixture parameters are set in `request.param`, so you can check for their existence, for example:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def passed_parameter(request):
    if hasattr(request, 'param'):
        if request.param == 'one':
            yield request.param + '_changed'
        else:
            yield request.param * 2
    else:
        yield 42

@pytest.mark.parametrize('passed_parameter', ['one', 'two'], indirect=True)
def test1(passed_parameter):
    print(passed_parameter)
    # first test prints "one_changed", second prints "twotwo"

def test2(passed_parameter):
    print(passed_parameter)
    # prints 42
```

Note that you cannot pass the parameter as a fixture argument, if that was your intention. Arguments passed to a fixture must be other (existing) fixtures.
Also note that the argument name must match the fixture name in this case.

EDIT: Changed the example to use indirect parameters to be able to yield fixture results different from the parameter, and made it self-contained.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense but the thing is that I store some other information in this `passed_parameter` which I need to use inside `test1` and if I do as showed in your example I just no longer have access to the original `passed_parameter` and it's value is just equal to `one` or `two`. I use yield in this `passed_parameter` so I can use it in `test1` like this: `passed_parameter.call_some_function`

Comment: I changed the example to use indirect parameters - check if this is what you need.